# How to display many maps from google api on one page

Tags: google-maps, maps

How to display many maps from my database on one page (GOOGLE MAP API) ? 
For example , I have publications with locations and I would like to make a request from database and display many maps on my page.

Look at my code :

head :

```
<?php
    // lancement de la requête (on impose aucune condition puisque l'on désire obtenir la liste complète des propriétaires
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM statuts WHERE "'.$membre_id.'" AND (NOT(lat="")) AND (NOT(lon=""))';

    // on lance la requête (mysql_query) et on impose un message d'erreur si la requête ne se passe pas bien (or die)
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br />'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());

    // on va scanner tous les tuples un par un
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {


    ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
                function initialisation(){
                    var centreCarte = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $data['lat'];?>, <?php echo $data['lon'];?>);
                    var optionsCarte = {
                        zoom: 14,
                        center: centreCarte,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte_<?php echo $data['id_statut'];?>"), optionsCarte);
                    var optionsMarqueur = {
                        position: maCarte.getCenter(),
                        map: maCarte
                    };
                    var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarqueur);
                 }
                 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialisation);
            </script>
        <?php
        }
    mysql_free_result ($req);
    mysql_close ();
    ?>
```

body :

```
<div style="width:80%;height:300px;" id="carte_<?php echo $row['id_statut'];?>"></div>
```

Comment: What problem are you having displaying multiple maps?  Are you getting errors?  What happens with the code you have posted?  Multiple functions with the same name will be problematic (just like multiple divs with same name would have been).

Comment: It only shows the same map every publication

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue with 2 maps and doesn't require us to run your PHP or connect to your database.

Comment: It only load on map every time ; Look what happens : http://gaspesia.co/bombr/profil.php?id=3

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it worked, I just figure it out that the coords was the same.